# Proof reference for the following theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let X be a supermartingale. The function $t \mapsto E\{X_t\} $is right continuous iff there is exists a modification Y of X which is cadlag. Such a modification is unique.

I just beagn  reading the book on Stochastic Integration by Protter and was looking for the proof of Theorem 9 which is stated above. Can somebody point me to a book or a place where I could find it?
Thank you

Comment: That is Doob's regularization theorem. There is a proof of it in the book of Williams and Rogers (Diffusions, Markov processes, and martingales).

Comment: @Calculon Thanks a ton!!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @user3503589 : An alternative source is Karatzas and Shreve's book Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus or even the blog of George Lowther  almost sure entry untitled "Cadlag Modifications".

Comment: @TheBridge I found the proof Thank you very much .